# Pass Http Get and Http Post as asynchronous apex in order

Tags: httprequest, asynchronous, queueable-apex

My requirement is to pass data from my org (Salesforce) to external org (SAP S4). I have successfully made the class for integrating both. However, I need to pass this class in a trigger and since it is an http class, I need to make it an asynchronous class so that it can run with the trigger active(future or queueable).

For the integration part, I need to use GET method first in order to get cookies and security tokens. After this, I use the POST method to send whatever data I have along with the cookies and security tokens so that I don't get a 403/400 error. I have added both the GET and POST method in the same class. Since the **methods should pass in order** (GET then POST), I need to use the queueable apex but I do no know how to add both the methods in queueable apex. I will post my code below for better understanding. The main class is a big class with many inner class and multiple methods. I have added how the JSON structure should look at the **bottom** so that the part of the code which makes the JSON structure will not get confusing. That whole part just makes the JSON structure the way I want so that I can add it in the body of the POST request.

```
    public class ReLearn2 {
    Static String accessKey;  //creating a string variable to store the x-csrf token
    Static String Cookie;    //creating a string to store the cookies
    
   
    
    //GET Callout code
    public static void IntegrationGet(){
        Http http = new Http();  
        HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://103.149.113.116:8001/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner');  //this is the endpoint URL      
        req.setMethod('GET');
        
        String username = '****';        
        String password = '****';            
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);        
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);     
        
        //Debugging just to check if the username password is encoded in the format
        
        System.debug(authorizationHeader);
        
        //Adding all headers
        
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);        
        req.setHeader('content-type','application/JSON');        
        req.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');        
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');      
        req.setHeader('x-csrf-token','fetch');
        
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        system.debug(res.getHeader('x-csrf-token'));
        Cookie = res.getHeader('Set-Cookie');
        system.debug(Cookie);        
        
        //Placing the value of the X-CSRF Token in the variable created above
        
        accessKey = res.getHeader('x-csrf-token');        
       
        //Debugging all to check 
        
        System.debug(res.getBody());     
        System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
        system.debug(res.getHeaderKeys());
                      
    }
    
    //method just to check the variables' values
    public void Debug(){                        
        System.debug(accessKey);
        System.debug(Cookie);
    }
    
    
    
    
    //POST Callout code
    public static void IntegrationPost(){
        
        Http hr = new Http();
        HTTPRequest re = new HTTPRequest();
        re.setEndpoint('http://103.149.113.116:8001/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner');     //This is the endpoint URL    
        re.setMethod('POST');
        
        String username = '****';        
        String password = '*****';            
        Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);        
        String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
        
        //Debugging just to check if the username password is encoded in the format
        
        System.debug(authorizationHeader);  
        
        //Adding all headers
        
        re.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
        re.setHeader('content-type','application/json');        
        re.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');            
        re.setHeader('x-csrf-token',accessKey);
        re.setHeader('Cookie',Cookie);
        
        
        System.debug(accessKey);
        
        //Setting the Body to be used in POST callout from method LGS() below
        
        re.setBody(Relearn2.LGS());
        
        HTTPResponse resp = hr.send(re);
        System.debug(re.getBody());
        
        if(resp.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + resp.getStatusCode() + ' ' + resp.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(resp.getBody());
            System.debug(resp.getStatus());
        }
 
        
 ////////////////////////////////Creating JSON strcuture///////////////////////////////////////////       
 
    
    }
    class SapData{                         // Inner class properties
        String BusinessPartnerCategory;
        String OrganizationBPName1;
        BusinessPartnerAddress[] to_BusinessPartnerAddress;       //Inner class with an array variable
        T0BusinessPartnerTax[] to_BusinessPartnerTax ;            //Inner class with an array variable
    }
    
    class BusinessPartnerAddress {                             //1st array properties
        String Country;
        String StreetName;
        String PostalCode;
        String CityName;
        AddressUsage[] to_AddressUsage;                         //1st array with an inner array
    }
    
    class AddressUsage {                                        //inner-inner array property
        String AddressUsage; 
    }
    
    class T0BusinessPartnerTax {                              //2nd array properties
        String BPTaxType;
        String BPTaxNumber;
    }
    
                                                          //Future method as this entire class i will copy in an http post class to be triggered via a trigger
    public static String LGS(){                               
        //Querying the required records - where checkbox is ticked
        List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Name, MobilePhone, Fax, Phone, MailingCountry, MailingStreet, MailingPostalCode, MailingCity, MailingState FROM Contact WHERE Create_SAP_record__c = TRUE];  
        String MyHttpRequestBody;
        
        
        SapData sapData = new SapData();                   //creating instance of class
        
        for(Contact con : conList){
            
            //creating for loop to give values of the respective fields
            
            sapData.OrganizationBPName1 = con.Name;                   
            sapData.BusinessPartnerCategory = con.Phone;
            
            T0BusinessPartnerTax businessPartnerTax = new T0BusinessPartnerTax();          //2nd array instance
            businessPartnerTax.BPTaxType = con.MobilePhone;
            businessPartnerTax.BPTaxNumber = con.Fax;
            
            sapData.to_BusinessPartnerTax = new List<T0BusinessPartnerTax>{businessPartnerTax};       //adding this (2nd array) array to main class instance
            
            BusinessPartnerAddress businessPartnerAddress = new BusinessPartnerAddress();           //1st array instance
            
            businessPartnerAddress.Country = con.MailingCountry;
            businessPartnerAddress.StreetName = con.MailingStreet;
            businessPartnerAddress.PostalCode = con.MailingPostalCode;
            businessPartnerAddress.CityName = con.MailingCity;
            
            AddressUsage toAddressUsage = new AddressUsage();                                        //1st array inner-inner array instance
            businessPartnerAddress.to_AddressUsage = new List<AddressUsage> {toAddressUsage};        //initialising the inner inner array instance to a list
                toAddressUsage.AddressUsage = con.MailingState;
            
            
            sapData.to_BusinessPartnerAddress = new List<BusinessPartnerAddress>{businessPartnerAddress};       //adding the 1st array to main class              
                                    
            
        }
        
        MyHttpRequestBody = JSON.serialize(sapData);                                           //serializing data
        System.debug(JSON.serialize(sapData));                                       //debugging for checking format
        return JSON.serialize(sapData);
    }
    
}
```

Here is how my JSON structure should look like :

```
[
"BusinessPartnerCategory": "2",
"OrganizationBPName": "Test Contact Name",
"to_BusinessPartnerAddress": [
    {
        "Country" : "Test Contact Country",
        "StreetName" : "Test Contact StreetName",
        "PostalCode" : "Test Contact PostalCode",
        "CityName" : "Test Contact City",
        "t0_AddressUsage" : [
                            { 
                            "AddressUsage" : "Test Contact AddressUsage"
                            }
                            ]
    }
]
"to_BusinessPartnerTax" : [
     {
       "BPTaxType" : "Test Contact TaxType",
       "BPTaxNumber" : "Test Contact TaxNumber"
     }
     ]
]
```

**EDIT AFTER**

```
public with sharing class ReLearn2 implements Queueable{
Static String accessKey;  //creating a string variable to store the x-csrf token
Static String Cookie;    //creating a string to store the cookies

public void execute(QueueableContext qc){
    ReLearn2.IntegrationGet();
    ReLearn2.IntegrationPost();
}

@future(callout= true)
public static void IntegrationGet(){
    Http http = new Http();  
    HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('http://103.149.113.116:8001/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner');  //this is the endpoint URL      
    req.setMethod('GET');
    
    String username = '*****';        
    String password = '*****';            
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);        
    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);     
    
    //Debugging just to check if the username password is encoded in the format
    
    System.debug(authorizationHeader);
    
    //Adding all headers
    
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);        
    req.setHeader('content-type','application/JSON');        
    req.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');        
    req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');      
    req.setHeader('x-csrf-token','fetch');
    
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    system.debug(res.getHeader('x-csrf-token'));
    Cookie = res.getHeader('Set-Cookie');
    system.debug(Cookie);        
    
    //Placing the value of the X-CSRF Token in the variable created above
    
    accessKey = res.getHeader('x-csrf-token');        
    
    //Debugging all to check 
    
    System.debug(res.getBody());     
    System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
    system.debug(res.getHeaderKeys());
    if(System.IsBatch() == false && System.isFuture() == false){ 
    }
    
}

//method just to check the variables' values
public void Debug(){                        
    System.debug(accessKey);
    System.debug(Cookie);
}




@future(callout = true)
public static void IntegrationPost(){
    
    Http hr = new Http();
    HTTPRequest re = new HTTPRequest();
    re.setEndpoint('http://103.149.113.116:8001/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner');     //This is the endpoint URL    
    re.setMethod('POST');
    
    String username = '*****';        
    String password = '*****';            
    Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);        
    String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
    
    //Debugging just to check if the username password is encoded in the format
    
    System.debug(authorizationHeader);  
    
    //Adding all headers
    
    re.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
    re.setHeader('content-type','application/json');        
    re.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');            
    re.setHeader('x-csrf-token',accessKey);
    re.setHeader('Cookie',Cookie);
    
    
    System.debug(accessKey);
    
    //Setting the Body to be used in POST callout from method LGS() below
    
    re.setBody(Relearn2.LGS());
    
    HTTPResponse resp = hr.send(re);
    System.debug(re.getBody());
    
    if(resp.getStatusCode() != 201) {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + resp.getStatusCode() + ' ' + resp.getStatus());
    } else {
        System.debug(resp.getBody());
        System.debug(resp.getStatus());
    }
}
```

**anonymous window**

```
ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new ReLearn2());
```

Comment: You should search for questions on how to use queueables to make callouts from triggers. This question has been answered before. You basically have a queueable that makes the GET callout and then the POST. The primary design issues revolve around avoiding limits.  All the JSON construction is besides the point and can be abstracted

Comment: I have edited my code to implement a queuable interface, However it is still not working as I get error such as  Argument 2 cannot be null (this is because the GET method is still getting executed last)

Comment: the get and the post should not be separate future methods as those run in separate transactions in no guaranteed order

Comment: I have successfully completed the task finally. I used only 1 future method by combining the GET and POST methods as  a single method. I have updated the code above to show what I have done. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My new code :**

```
public with sharing class ReLearn2{
Public Static String accessKeyy;  //creating a string variable to store the x-csrf token
    Public Static String Cookiee;    //creating a string to store the cookies
    
    @future(callout=true)
    Public static void IntegrationGet(){
        Http http = new Http();  
        HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://103.149.113.116:8001/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner');  //this is the endpoint URL      
        req.setMethod('GET');
        
        String username1 = '&&&&';        
        String password1 = '))(*&&^';            
        Blob headerValue1 = Blob.valueOf(username1 + ':' + password1);        
        String authorizationHeader1 = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue1);       
        
        //Debugging just to check if the username password is encoded in the format
        
        System.debug(authorizationHeader1);
        
        //Adding all headers
        
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader1);        
        req.setHeader('content-type','application/JSON');        
        req.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');        
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');      
        req.setHeader('x-csrf-token','fetch');
        
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        system.debug(res.getHeader('x-csrf-token'));
        Cookiee = res.getHeader('Set-Cookie');
        system.debug(Cookiee);        
        
        //Placing the value of the X-CSRF Token in the variable created above
        
        accessKeyy = res.getHeader('x-csrf-token');        
        
        //Debugging all to check 
        
        System.debug(res.getBody());     
        System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
        system.debug(res.getHeaderKeys());
        //if(System.IsBatch() == false && System.isFuture() == false){ 
        //}
        
        Http hr = new Http();
        HTTPRequest re = new HTTPRequest();
        re.setEndpoint('http://103.149.113.116:8001/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BUSINESS_PARTNER/A_BusinessPartner');     //This is the endpoint URL    
        re.setMethod('POST');
        
        String username2 = '*****';        
        String password2 = '********';            
        Blob headerValue2 = Blob.valueOf(username2 + ':' + password2);        
        String authorizationHeader2 = 'BASIC ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue2);
        
        //Debugging just to check if the username password is encoded in the format
        
        System.debug(authorizationHeader2);  
        
        //Adding all headers
        
        re.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader2);
        re.setHeader('content-type','application/json');        
        re.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');            
        re.setHeader('x-csrf-token',accessKeyy);
        re.setHeader('Cookie',Cookiee);
        
        
        System.debug(accessKeyy);
        
        //Setting the Body to be used in POST callout from method LGS() below
        
        re.setBody(Relearn2.LGS());
        
        HTTPResponse resp = hr.send(re);
        System.debug(re.getBody());
        
        if(resp.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' + resp.getStatusCode() + ' ' + resp.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(resp.getBody());
            System.debug(resp.getStatus());
        }
        
    }
    
    
       
        ////////////////////////////////Creating JSON strcuture///////////////////////////////////////////       
        
        
    
    class SapData{                         // Inner class properties
        String BusinessPartnerCategory;
        String OrganizationBPName1;
        BusinessPartnerAddress[] to_BusinessPartnerAddress;       //Inner class with an array variable
        T0BusinessPartnerTax[] to_BusinessPartnerTax ;            //Inner class with an array variable
    }
    
     class BusinessPartnerAddress {                             //1st array properties
        String Country;
        String StreetName;
        String PostalCode;
        String CityName;
        AddressUsage[] to_AddressUsage;                         //1st array with an inner array
    }
    
    class AddressUsage {                                        //inner-inner array property
        String AddressUsage; 
    }
    
    class T0BusinessPartnerTax {                              //2nd array properties
        String BPTaxType;
        String BPTaxNumber;
    }
    
    //Future method as this entire class i will copy in an http post class to be triggered via a trigger
    public static String LGS(){                               
        //Querying the required records - where checkbox is ticked
        List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Name, MobilePhone, Fax, Phone, MailingCountry, MailingStreet, MailingPostalCode, MailingCity, MailingState FROM Contact WHERE Create_SAP_record__c = TRUE];  
        String MyHttpRequestBody;
        
        
        SapData sapData = new SapData();                   //creating instance of class
        
        for(Contact con : conList){
            
            //creating for loop to give values of the respective fields
            
            sapData.OrganizationBPName1 = con.Name;                   
            sapData.BusinessPartnerCategory = con.Phone;
            
            T0BusinessPartnerTax businessPartnerTax = new T0BusinessPartnerTax();          //2nd array instance
            businessPartnerTax.BPTaxType = con.MobilePhone;
            businessPartnerTax.BPTaxNumber = con.Fax;
            
            sapData.to_BusinessPartnerTax = new List<T0BusinessPartnerTax>{businessPartnerTax};       //adding this (2nd array) array to main class instance
                
                BusinessPartnerAddress businessPartnerAddress = new BusinessPartnerAddress();           //1st array instance
            
            businessPartnerAddress.Country = con.MailingCountry;
            businessPartnerAddress.StreetName = con.MailingStreet;
            businessPartnerAddress.PostalCode = con.MailingPostalCode;
            businessPartnerAddress.CityName = con.MailingCity;
            
            AddressUsage toAddressUsage = new AddressUsage();                                        //1st array inner-inner array instance
            businessPartnerAddress.to_AddressUsage = new List<AddressUsage> {toAddressUsage};        //initialising the inner inner array instance to a list
                toAddressUsage.AddressUsage = con.MailingState;
            
            
            sapData.to_BusinessPartnerAddress = new List<BusinessPartnerAddress>{businessPartnerAddress};       //adding the 1st array to main class              
                
                
                }
        
        MyHttpRequestBody = JSON.serialize(sapData);                                           //serializing data
        System.debug(JSON.serialize(sapData));                                       //debugging for checking format
        return JSON.serialize(sapData);
    }
    
}
```

**My trigger :**

```
trigger SAPTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update) {
for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
    if(con.Create_SAP_record__c == true){
        ReLearn2.IntegrationGet();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Congratulations on making it this far! It's worth noting that your implementation will fail whenever the trigger is hit with > 50 records that have `Create_SAP_Record__c = true` - see [Limits Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). If you search this site and others, you'll see patterns for how to handle that. Also: Putting passwords in code is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes I forgot to remove the characters in the excitement!. Thanks again though!